# React-native install issue in expo app

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

I'm trying to learn react-native by creating an app using the expo development environment. I had a working app (little more than the code that shipped with expo) until installing redux. Currently I am getting the following error from the XDE:

```
Problem checking node_modules dependencies: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

and the following from the ios simulator:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ReactPropTypes.string')
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Hello Expo!",
  "author": null,
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/ex-navigation": "~3.0.0",
    "@expo/samples": "~1.0.3",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "expo": "17.0.0",
    "react": "^16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "^0.45.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "redux": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest-expo": "~1.0.1"
  }
}
```

I believe my node modules contain valid JSON. It should be noted that I'm using a more current version of react-native than expo. Is this an issue with the packages I have installed? Which files would be helpful in solving this?

Comment: what does your `package.json` look like?

Comment: @QoP I added it to my question.

Comment: Did you do npm install?

Comment: @Kun yes, many times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I haven't been able to fix this particular error. This one and many others can be avoided by using yarn instead of npm when working with expo (I have no affiliation with either tool).

Comment: `yarn start` stuck in same place for a long time, but then after a 3 or 4 minute wait it suddenly continued ok. 

In expo they say not to update even if you see it recommended. 

See here for example in [expokit install instructions](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/expokit)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to a bug in the current release of npm 5. As mentioned in the other answer here, using npm 4 or yarn will resolve this problem.